# The right syntax for using auto_increment

Tags: mysql

The sql statement in mysql below.

```
CREATE TABLE `dcc_native_app`.`user` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `loggedin` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

It reports a `AUTO_INCREMENT syntax` error.

Comment: Leave out `DEFAULT` before `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: Your problem is nothing more than a typo. Please read [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) before asking.

Comment: Sorry for that, I just using mysql workbench automatically generate this sql and not aware of this is a typo problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loggedin` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: Suggest not changing the length and size of 3/4 of the columns when posting an aswer. Giving the same table name would be nice too.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that :)